# MockMvc REST controller - always returns empty body

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockmvc

I would like to test my REST controller using MockMvc but I always get an empty body response.

My `AccountControllerUnitTest` looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(AccountRestController.class)
public class AccountRestControllerUnitTests {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean(name = "dtoUtil")
private DtoUtil dtoUtil;

@MockBean
private AccountService accountService;

@Test
public void canRetrieveAll() throws Exception {
    when(accountService.findAll())
            .thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(AccountTestFixture.createAccount()));

    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/accounts")).andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}}
```

The `accountService when mock` works as expected, calling `accountService.findAll()` returns a list with a single account element.

With my used `AccountRestController` being:

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/accounts")
public class AccountRestController {
    private AccountService accountService;

    @Qualifier(dtoUtil)
    private DtoUtil dtoUtil;

    @GetMapping
    public List<AccountDto> getAccounts() {
        return accountService.findAll().stream()
                .map(dtoUtil::mapToDto)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Running the test will result in a `MockHttpServletResponse` with a body that is `null`.

It works flawlessly for my normal (non-rest that has a model) controller, the only difference being that it doesn't use the `DtoUtil`.

Could that be the reason for it constantly returning null?

edit:

The `DtoUtil`:

```
@Component
public class DtoUtil{

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper mapper;

    public AccountDto mapToDto(Account account) {
        return modelMapper.map(account, AccountDto.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add to your test

```
when(dtoUtil.mapToDto(...)).thenCallRealMethod();
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I go about injecting the `ModelMapper` used in the `DtoUtil` though? As its currently a mockedBean in the unit test, the modelMapper is null.

Or should I just generate a new AccountDTO and return that?

Comment: @Martens you didn't paste any code for you DtoUtil, but the easiest way would be to create DtoUtil object and all its dependencies manually (`new` ... ) and then call this object's mapToDto() method like `when(dtoUtil.mapToDto(...)).thenAnswer(call previously created DtoUtil.mapToDto() )`

Comment: I added the DtoUtil class, would creating it new still be the best way?

Comment: Personally, I would mock the `DtoUtil.mapToDto()` the same way you mocked `accountService.findAll()`. This would allow you to test only the code within your controller method, avoiding bugs in `DtoUtil.mapToDto()` causing your controller tests to fail (of course you have to have another set of tests for your DtoUtil).